# Identity function

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

I was told that identity functions have the definition when followed.

If f ∘ e = f, e = id<sub>x</sub>. If e ∘ f = f, e = id<sub>y</sub>.

The textbook had a question below the definition asking, for any functions f and g, does either of g ∘ f = id<sub>x</sub>, f ∘ g = id<sub>y</sub> implies the other.

My answer was,

f ∘ g = id<sub>y</sub>

f ∘ g ∘ f = id<sub>y</sub> ∘ f = f

f ∘ (g ∘ f) = f

(g ∘ f)  = id<sub>x</sub> (from the definition of f ∘ e = f, e = id<sub>x</sub>)

and similarly

g ∘ f = id<sub>x</sub>

f ∘ g ∘ f = f ∘ id<sub>x</sub> = f

(f ∘ g) ∘ f = f

(f ∘ g)  = id<sub>y</sub> (from the definition of e ∘ f = f, e = id<sub>y</sub>)

But the answer was, no they do not imply the other and it didn't give me the proof, but showed a counter example.

[counter example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLr47.png)

Okay, I understand the counter example, but where in my proof has gone wrong? I didn't assume anything, just followed definition in the proof.

Edit: The text book says, (translated)

> Let's figure out whether identity and inverse elements exist for *composite*s. The identity element is a function e that satisfies, f ∘ e = e ∘ f = f for all f: X->Y. However, the function that satisfies f ∘ e = f is e: X->X, and the function that satisfies e ∘ f = f is e: Y->Y and hence they are different. Therefore, identity element of composites does not exist nor the inverse element. Despite this, we define the function e that satisfies f ∘ e = f as the identity function of X and write as id_X, and the function e that satisfies e ∘ f = f as the identity function of Y and write as id_Y. For each set, there exists one identity function.

Edit2: updated some lines for readability

Comment: Who told you that definition?  It's totally wrong...

Comment: @EricWofsey in a textbook I am using. What is correct then?

Comment: If $f(x) = x^2$ and if $e(x) = -x$ then $f\circ e(x)= f(-x) = (-x)^2 = x^2 = f(x)$.  So does that mean $e$ is the identity function? Are different functions supposed to have different function because if $g(x) = e^x$ then $g\circ e(x) = e^{-x} \ne g(x)$.  Are some functions supposed to have more than one identity function. .... (In short I think either the book or you screwed up on the *definition*.  That is *not* the definition but it is a consequence.

Comment: Usually the identy function is simply defined as $e: x\mapsto x$ for all $x$ in the domain.

Comment: @fleablood the text book does say that functions have different identity function. I am not sure about multiple identity function part though. It just stated that if f o e = f, we call e, idx

Comment: Oh, I see.  function composition as an operation.  To make identity function***s***.  The books okay.  I apologize fro getting confused.

Comment: Okay, what do the subscripts ${}_X$ and ${}_Y$ mean?

Comment: Is this an abstract algebra text book?  Are there any restrictions on the functions?  Are they all 1-1 and onto.  Do they all have the same domains and codomains.   You define $Id_X=e$ as the function where $f\circ e = f$.  Is that supposed to be true for *all* $f$.  Has it been proven there *is* such a function?  That it is unique?  This is just too.... strange.... without context.

Comment: I would suggest you write down the _exact_ definition in your book, word for word.  You may be leaving out some very important words which totally change the meaning.

Comment: I think the definition is supposed to be that the $Id_X$ exists for *all* functions.  $f\circ (g\circ f)  = f$ for *that* $f$.  But you have no idea that $h \circ (g\circ f) = h$.

Comment: @fleablood it says for all function f. It also states that each set has its own identity function. I am guessing the set implies the domain and codomain, so for f: x->y, two identity functions id_x, id_y exists

Comment: @EricWofsey I may be doing that, I will update the question. It is not in English so I would have to translate.

Comment: @EricWofsey updated. Thanks for the help

Comment: @fleablood I updated the post including the original text from the book

Comment: @fleablood I think I am starting to understand where you are going and also the answer below by Jose. We may be talking about something slightly different. So identity function is not a property of a specific function but it applies to all functions? The definition I was given, "we define the function e that satisfies f ∘ e = f as the identity function of X and write as idx" seems to imply that the id_X is a specific funciton of f hence id_X

Comment: I'm not seeing why it is assumed $id_X$ is a left identity and $id_Y$ is a right identity.  But the way I see it $id_X$ is defined for a set $X$ so $id_X: X\to X$.  For any $f:FOO\to X$ then $f\circ id_X=f: FOO \to X\to X$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have no justification for jumping from$$f\circ(g\circ f)=f\implies g\circ f=\operatorname{id}_X,\tag1$$to $g\circ f=\operatorname{id}_X$. In fact, if $f$ was injective then, yes, you could deduce that $(1)$ hods, but all that you can deduce from $f\circ g=\operatorname{id}_Y$ is that $f$ is surjective, not that it is injective.

Comment: f∘(g∘f)=f is in a from of f ∘ e = f isn't it? So from the definition I am given, g∘f = e = idx.

Comment: I have no idea about what you mean with “is in a form of”. Yes, $f\circ\operatorname{id}_X=f$, but what you asserted was that $f\circ(g\circ f)=f\implies g\circ f=\operatorname{id}_X$, without justification.

Comment: Okay if I say h = g o f, f o (g o f) = f becomes f o h = f. What I am saying is that this is the definition of idx I am given. f o e = f, e = idx. So f o (g o f) = f, (g o f) = idx. Sorry for the unbearable readability here.

Comment: Yes, $\operatorname{id}_X$ is the only function from $X$ into itself such that for **every** $f\colon X\longrightarrow Y$, $f\circ\operatorname{id}_X=f$. But for a **specific** $f\colon X\longrightarrow Y$ there may be *other* functions from $X$ into itself (besides $\operatorname{id}_X$) with the same property.

Comment: For the first line of your comment: Are you saying the id_X is universal? For all functions, they have the same id_X? I thought id_X is a property of a function. Second line: That means there may exist multiple functions e that satisfies f o e = f. Are those other functions not identity functions then? Only the _universal_ id_X is the identity function?

Comment: I don't understand your first question and therefore I can't answer it. The answer to the second question is affirmative.

Comment: The book I am referring to seems to be implying that identity functions id_X and id_Y is function-specific not something universal that applies to all functions. The definition I was given, "we define the function e that satisfies f ∘ e = f as the _identity_ _function_ *of* X and write as id_X". The original post is updated and includes the text from the book. It does mention about *identity* *element* for all functions, and it says it doesn't exist for composites

Answer (score 0):

Okay.

You have two sets, $X$ and $Y$ and a class of functions that map $X \to Y$.  They want  to know if there is a function $id$ so that $id\circ f = f\circ id = f$ for any $f: X\to Y$.

I'm actually not sure why they even bothered to ask as the $id\circ f = f$ would require that $id: Y\to Y$ and $f\circ id = f$ would require $id:X\to X$ which is impossible as $X$ and $Y$ are different sets.

However then it asks if there are $id_X: X\to X$ that can act as a right identity with $f\circ id_X = f$ for all $f:X\to Y$.  The answer is, yes, the identity element $i:X\to X$ where $i(x) = x$ for all $x \in X$ is such an element and with a little bit of playing it's clear that that is the is the only such function from $X \to X$.

(If $h(x) = w \ne x$ then there is some function $f$ where $f(w) \ne f(x)$ and so $f(h(x)) = f(w) \ne f(x) $. So the only function that works is $i(x) = x$.)

Likewise $i:Y\to Y$ $i(y) = y$ can act as $id_Y: Y\to Y$ that can act as a left identity with $id_Y\circ f = f$ for all $f: X\to Y$.

So they are asking if you have a $g:Y\to X$ so that $g\circ f: X\to X = id_X$ or $f\circ g: Y\to Y= id_Y$ does one imply the other.

And the answer is no.

The thing is if $|X| > |Y|$ then $f: X \to Y$ can not be injective so there must be $w\in X,x \in X$ and $w\ne x$ so that $f(x)=f(w)$.  $g\circ f:X\to X$ can't be $id_x$.  $id_X(w) = w$ and $id_X(x) = x$ but $g\circ f(w) = g(f(w)) = g(f(x)) = g\circ f(x)$.

Comment: The question does not specify anything about function f or g. The answer, however, is given as a counterexample that uses f: X->Y, g: Y->X. With regards to your answer, I am trying to understand.

Comment: I think this link has something to say with regards to identity element and identity function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function#Algebraic_property.